# Crop the area used for title in google's area chart

Tags: google-visualization

The area chart used for the title is too big. I see the area used for allow the tooltip when there is a high value, but if is possible to cut the area used for the title, maybe the tooltip will render from top to bottom.

Is it possible to crop the area used for title (and maybe something more), like:

[image]

I just want the "chart draw" area, the red part should be cropped.

Tried `titlePosition: 'none'`, but it didn't work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The part of your chart that you labeled "chart draw" is controlled by the `chartArea` option:

```
chartArea: {
    top: 25,
    height: '80%'
}
```

Each sub-option (height, width, top, left) can be either a number (pixels) or a string (percent of total chart height or width).  Use these options to enlarge the chartArea's height and/or shrink the area devoted to the chart title.